# Socket error from Watir-webdriver with Firefox 6

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver

I am getting this error message while running my watir-webdriver tests on Firefox 6 for the first time on Windows XP.

```
  1) Error:
testAttributeGadget010_workflow_shown(AttributeGadgetTest):
Errno::EADDRINUSE: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port)   is normally permitted. - connect(2)
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:560:in `initialize'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:560:in `open'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:560:in `connect'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/timeout.rb:53:in `timeout'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/timeout.rb:101:in `timeout'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:560:in `connect'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:553:in `do_start'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:542:in `start'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:1035:in `request'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.4.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:73:in `response_for'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.4.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:41:in `request'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.4.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:34:in `call'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.4.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:410:in `raw_execute'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.4.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:388:in `execute'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.4.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:356:in `find_element_by'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.4.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/search_context.rb:41:in `find_element'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/watir-webdriver-0.3.2/lib/watir-webdriver/locators/element_locator.rb:86:in `find_first_by_multiple'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/watir-webdriver-0.3.2/lib/watir-webdriver/locators/element_locator.rb:33:in `locate'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/watir-webdriver-0.3.2/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/element.rb:263:in `locate'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/watir-webdriver-0.3.2/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/element.rb:245:in `assert_exists'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/watir-webdriver-0.3.2/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/checkbox.rb:19:in `set'
./library/attribOptions.rb:22:in `attribOptions'
./library/attribOptions.rb:20:in `each_index'
./library/attribOptions.rb:20:in `attribOptions'
./007_wb_attribute.rb:365:in `testAttributeGadget010_workflow_shown'
./007_wb_attribute.rb:345:in `each'
./007_wb_attribute.rb:345:in `testAttributeGadget010_workflow_shown'
```

Seems to have happen 20 times out of my 100+ Test/Unit test cases.
Has anyone any idea what is going wrong?

Comment: Can you try updating to ruby 1.9.2 and see if it persists?

Comment: I'm getting this same issue using various FF versions from 3.X to 6.0.  Selenium Webdriver 2.5.0, Watir-Webdriver 0.3.2, Ruby 192-p290.  On both XP (32-bit) and Windows 7 (64-bit) boxes.  I did update webdriver yesterday to resolve an issue running with Firefox 6, and the issue began directly after.

Comment: The Microsoft article appears to have resolved both issues on XP!

Comment: @jarib You should put your MaxUserPort answer as a proper answer so it can be marked as answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost sounds like you're running out of ephemeral ports, which shouldn't really happen with just one Firefox instance. But who knows with Windows. Try increasing the MaxUserPort setting as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa560610%28v=bts.20%29.aspx).

Comment: I've had to downgrade from 2.5.0 to 2.4.0 because of this issue, and I don't have admin rights on the machine to update the registry.

Comment: That's odd. I wouldn't think 2.4.0 would be any different.

Comment: This error happening coincided with me upgrading to 2.5.0, therefore I thought it was related, but it's not. Still happening on 2.4.0. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: I've added a rescue-and-retry to selenium-webdriver that should help with this for people who can't tweak the registry (http://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/detail?r=13802), but bumping the MaxUserPort or getting off XP are probably both better solutions.